# 'adduser' object has no attribute 'get' error while using templates with django?

Tags: python, django, templates, attributes, view

I am trying to use HTML templates with django but getting errors, please look into to it and tell me whats wrong with the code

This is my views file

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from . models import adduser
def user(request):
    all_users = adduser.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('p1/adduser.html')
    context = {
        'all_users':all_users,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

This is my models file

```
from django.db import models
class adduser(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)z
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    confirmpassword = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ContactNumber = models.IntegerField()
```

This is my adduser.html template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<h2>Add User</h2>

<form action="" method="post">
 Name:<br>
 <input type="text" name="Name"><br>
 Designation:<br>
 <input type="text" name="Designation"><br>
 Email:<br>
 <input type="Email" name="Email"><br>
 Password:<br>
 <input type="password" name="Password"><br>
 Confirm Password:<br>
 <input type="password" name="Confirm Password"><br>
 Contact Number:<br>
 <input type="number" name="Number" ><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Add">
 <button type="cancel" onclick="window.location='http://google.com';return false;">Cancel</button>
   
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably constructed a view named `adduser`, and since it is the same as your model, those start to cause trouble. Do not name models like this, it is a user, not an "adduser", furthermore follow PEP-8 naming conventions.

Comment: @swapnil Please paste the error so that we can track more

Comment: There was a error in my urls file which i corrected, now the code is working and I can see the template on the url, But I want to save the data from this template to mySQL database. How can I do that?